# Angular is not running on fresh ubuntu installation

Tags: node.js, angular, linux, ubuntu

I got a fresh new Linux server, installed my project - Frontend (Angular) Backend (NodeJs). However, when I try to preview my angular on (IP:4200) it does not work. I did a couple of attempts tried,

`ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` and `ng serve --host x.x.x.x` I changed the port to `8080` and `ng serve --open`

I tried `ng serve --host=0.0.0.0 --disable-host-check`

and different ports and still no luck.

[image]

The output of `ng version`
[image]

Comment: where you host can you check this port and your http TCP rule is enable to access this using IP ?

Comment: Can you please advise, how to check this? I checked for firewall and it is disabled.

Comment: are you able to ping this IP in console ?  "ping 77.68.4.154" which hosting provider using ? AWS EC2 ?

Comment: Yes, I can ping the IP. Not AWS EC2 it is some other hosting company.

Comment: you can run build for running angular project. Why you want to run this as server mode ?

Comment: I wanted to run it as a server mode for testing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204749/discussion-between-aviboy2006-and-mmsa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you open this port in your firewall if you using other hosting provider.

Like in AWS EC2

you can do this in security group :

Reference : https://medium.com/@ramesh18492/deploying-angular-app-in-amazon-ec2-server-f2ca87a1dceb

[image]

Another way you can try running serve command :

```
ng serve --host 77.68.4.154 -- port 4200
```

If proper approach to run Angular project is creating build.

```
ng build --aot
```

Then build will get created in `dist/` folder. While in your Apache configuration your can configure 80 port to serve /var/www/html/angular-project/dist/

file path for configuration:  /etc/apache2/site-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName www.example.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/angular-project/dist/
</VirtualHost>
```

This will run directly on your IP.

Here is more details to help : https://medium.com/@sandeeptengale/deploy-angular-app-on-aws-ec2-instance-20749f17b33e

Feel free to ask if any question!

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed angular cli on your machine?

```
1. If angular cli is not installed on your machine, Please install angular cli using npm i -g @angular/cli@latest.
```

```
2.If angular cli installed on your machine, then please try ng serve --open command to run your project on browser.
```

Comment: Yes, I did try both and no luck.

Comment: Are you getting any error when you are running ng serve --open?

Comment: @MMSA, could you try running following command
echo 65536 | sudo tee -a /proc/sys/fs/inotify/max_user_watches

Comment: The command output is : 65536 and no error when I run the ng serve --open

Comment: @MMSA, could you share me the output of the follwing command:
ng version